# Mean curvature of parametric curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, curves, curvature

I am trying to calculate the mean curvature of a curve parametrized by $( x(t), y(t))$ in a two-dimensional space with ambient metric $g$. I know one formula for the mean curvature, $K = \nabla_i \hat{n}^i$ where $\nabla_i$ is the covariant derivative with respect to $g$ and $\hat{n}^i$ is the unit normal vector. I can write $\hat{n}^i$ in terms of the functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, and their first derivatives. I get stuck trying to calculate things like $\partial_x \hat{n}^x$. What is $\partial_x x'(t)$? Can I naively take this to equal $x''(t) / x'(t)$? If I do so, I seem to get the wrong result, but I am not sure if I am making a mistake or I have an incorrect understanding.

To be concrete, I am taking the hyperbolic metric $g_{xx} = g_{yy} = 1/y^2$. I can then write the normal vector as
$$ \hat{n} = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x'^2 + y'^2}} (y', -x') $$
Thank you for taking the time to answer this. I am trying to calculate the extrinsic curvature term $K$ in the Gibbons-Hawking boundary term.

Comment: I presume that by mean curvature of a curve in a surface you just mean its geodesic curvature. So all you have to do is compute the curvature of the curve. In general, mean curvature is defined for an (oriented) hypersurface in a Riemannian manifold. At any rate, to proceed as you are doing, you cannot just compute partial derivatives; you need *covariant* derivatives, which means you need Christoffel symbols. (You might find the section on hyperbolic geometry in [my differential geometry text](https://math.franklin.uga.edu/sites/default/files/inline-files/ShifrinDiffGeo.pdf) helpful.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like your notes -- I remember taking a class like this a long time ago. For me, finding the Christoffel terms is the easy part. I am stuck taking ill-defined derivatives.


I think I know my issue: i plugged in for my curve too early. Instead of taking derivatives of $\hat{n}^i(t)$, I probably should find a normal vector _field_ $\hat{n}^i(x, y)$, take derivatives of that, and then plug in for my curve. I will try that now.

Comment: Ah never mind. Thank you for the keyword! This helped: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeodesicCurvature.html

Comment: My notes would help, too. But glad you're on your way.